# Transaction not getting rolled back for when exception throws in child method - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a method Service method - SampleServiceImpl().
I have declared the Service method as following:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public sampleDTO SampleServiceImpl(SampleDTO sampleDTO) throws SampleException, ParseException { 
   // Method call to methodA.
   createDataA(sampleDTO);
   // Method call to methodB.
   createDataB(sampleDTO);

   return sampleDTO ;
}
```

Here the DataA is created and it does not throw any exception.
But in DataB, we are trying to create DataB based on DataA. Due to some logic, we cannot create DataB. So, we throw a Sample Exception like:

```
count = checkIfDataBExisting(sampleDTO);
if(count == 1){
   throw new SampleException(ErrorConstants.DATA_B_EXISTING);
}
```

But the problem is, the transaction that got committed during  **createDataA(sampleDTO)** method call, does not get rolled Back.

Why does this don't actually work? I'm bit confused with this behavior.

**EDIT:1**

*createData1(sampleDTO) method -*

```
private ADTO createDataA(SampleDTO sampleDTO) throws SampleException{
    ADTO aDTO = null;    
    try {
        //CREATE NEW WORK DRIVER
        aDTO = createNewDataA(sampleDTO);

        //Other arbitary database transactions occurs after creation of AData.


} catch (SampleException exc) {
    SampleException newException = new SampleException (exc.getExceptionObject().getExceptionCode(), exc);

    throw newException ;
}
return aDTO;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

*SampleException Declaration -*

```
public class SampleException extends Exception{
    //Definitions and Declarations.
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the method `createDataA`?

Comment: show `createDataA` method, also did you set auto commit to false by default?

Comment: @Andronicus - I have recreated the createDataA() method for your reference.

Comment: Does the database and table types you use support transactions? If you are using MySQL make sure that you don't use MyISAM tables as t hose don't support transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes DB supports transactions. I use oracle here.

Comment: Then your `@Transactional` isn't setup properly, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: For other rest calls, this transaction works good and it rollbacks correctly. Not sure why here it is happening like this.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye How do you instantiate the bean that contains your @Transactional method? It will not work if you create the bean with `new`. You have to get the bean from the Spring context.

Comment: @Evgeni Dimitrov Instantiating the bean part in the sense, which part you are mentioning bro? Can u please elaborate. I don't get it. Sorry..

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye For the @Transactional to work the bean has to be taken from the context (e.g. @Autiwired in another bean). If you do something like `new MyServiceImpl().myTransactionalMethod(someArgument)` it will not work, because Spring does not know anything about that object instance.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I haven't instantiated any object for the bean class. I am just calling that method from Controller class to Service through Interface.

Answer (score 0):

By default declarative transactions rollback only for Runtime exceptions.
SampleException has to be RuntimeException for the Transaction to be rolled back.

Your method signature:

`public sampleDTO SampleServiceImpl(SampleDTO sampleDTO) throws SampleException, ParseException`

makes me think that SampleException is a checked one.

See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) for `@Transactional`:

> If no rules are relevant to the exception, it will be treated like DefaultTransactionAttribute (rolling back on RuntimeException and Error but not on checked exceptions).

You can either make `SampleException` extends `RuntimeException` or set the `rollbackFor` attribute of `@Transactional`.

Comment: I have added SampleException declarations too. I have tried setting up rollback attribute too to SampleException.class like --> rollbackFor = SampleException.class, but its not working.